# ANTLR - Implicit AND Tokens In Tree

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I’m trying to build a grammar that interprets user-entered text, search-engine style.  It will support the AND, OR, NOT and ANDNOT Boolean operators.  I have pretty much everything working, but I want to add a rule that two adjacent keywords outside of a quoted string implicitly are treated as in an AND clause.  For example:

cheese and crackers = cheese AND crackers

(up and down) or (left and right) = (up AND down) OR (left AND right)

cat dog “potbelly pig” = cat AND dog AND “potbelly pig”

I’m having trouble with the last one, and I’m hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.  Here’s my *.g file thus far, and please be nice, my ANTLR experience spans less than a work day:

```
grammar SearchEngine;

options { language = CSharp2; output = AST; }

@lexer::namespace { Demo.SearchEngine }
@parser::namespace { Demo.SearchEngine }

LPARENTHESIS : '(';
RPARENTHESIS : ')';

AND    : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d');
OR     : ('O'|'o')('R'|'r');
ANDNOT : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d')('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');
NOT    : ('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');

fragment CHARACTER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9');
fragment QUOTE     : ('"');
fragment SPACE     : (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C');

WS     : (SPACE) { $channel=HIDDEN; };
PHRASE : (QUOTE)(CHARACTER)+((SPACE)+(CHARACTER)+)+(QUOTE);
WORD   : (CHARACTER)+;

startExpression  : andExpression;
andExpression    : andnotExpression (AND^ andnotExpression)*;
andnotExpression : orExpression (ANDNOT^ orExpression)*;
orExpression     : notExpression (OR^ notExpression)*;
notExpression    : (NOT^)? atomicExpression;
atomicExpression : PHRASE | WORD | LPARENTHESIS! andExpression RPARENTHESIS!;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your AND-rule has the optional AND-keyword, you should create an imaginary AND-token and use a rewrite-rule to "inject" that token in your tree. In this case, you can't make use of ANTLR's short-hand `^` root-operator. You'll have to use the `->` rewrite operator.

Your `andExpression` should look like:

```
andExpression
  :  (andnotExpression        -> andnotExpression)
     (AND? a=andnotExpression -> ^(AndNode $andExpression $a))* 
  ;
```

A detailed description of this (perhaps cryptic) notation is given in Chapter 7, section ***Rewrite Rules in Subrules***, page 173-174 of [***The Definitive ANTLR Reference***](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference) by Terence Parr.

I ran a quick test to see if the grammar produces the proper AST with the new `andExpression` rule. After parsing the string `cat dog "potbelly and pig" and FOO`, the generated parser produced the following AST:

[alt text http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/7370/andtree.png](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/7370/andtree.png)

Note that the `AndNode` and `Root` are [imaginary tokens](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=96534).

If you want to know how to create the AST picture above, see this thread: [Visualizing an AST created with ANTLR (in a .Net environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856612/visualizing-an-ast-created-with-antlr-in-a-net-environment)

**EDIT**

When parsing both `one two three` and `(one two) three`, the following AST is created:

[alt text http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/2558/69551879.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/2558/69551879.png)

And when parsing `(one two) OR three`, the following AST is created:

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8779/73390353.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8779/73390353.png)

which seems to be the proper way in all cases.

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  My follow-up concern (now removed, and what your edit was directed at) was due to a bug in some enclosing C# code.

Comment: @BartKiers Iam having problems understanding your rewrite rule, even though i have the reference here. Could you please explain why the (..)(..) part is needed and what the dollar operator does?

Comment: @ThomAS, I don't think I can word it better than the supreme overlord of ANTLR... :)

Comment: @BartKiers can you name this construct so i can look it up? Iam having troubles to pin down the right documentation for parenthesis enclosed terms and the dollar operator.

Comment: @ThomAS, I don't know of an official name for this. I think of it as  a "recursive reference" (`$andExpression` being the recursive reference in the rule `andExpression`).