# ANTLR ignoring AST operators

Tags: antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, antlrworks

I am using the ^ and ! operators to set the root node and to not not be included in the AST, respectively.  However, it is not making a difference in the tree that is generated by ANTLRWorks.  So I am not sure if my grammar is incorrect or if ANTLRWorks just isn't creating a correct tree.

Here is an snippet of my grammar

```
expr
:   '('! logExpr ')'!;
```

These parenthesis should not be included in the AST.

```
addExpr
:   multExpr ( (PLUS|MINUS)^ multExpr )*;
```

The PLUS or MINUS should be the root node in the AST.

However neither of these things are happening the way I expect them to.  It makes no difference when I remove them or put them back. ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 ANTLR 3.4

Comment: Where did you look in Antlrworks to come to your conclusion. I also suppose you told antlr to output an ast?

Comment: @stryba The interpreter tab that shows a diagram of the tree. Or is this the parse tree rather than the AST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANTLRWorks' interpreter shows the parse tree, even though you've put `output=AST;` in the grammar's options-block, as you already found yourself.

However, ANTLRWorks' debugger *does* show the AST. To activate the debugger, press <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or select <kbd>Run</kbd>`->`<kbd>Debug</kbd> from the menu bar.

The debugger is able to visualize the parse tree and AST. Note that it will *not* handle embedded code other than Java.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  ANTLRWorks shows the parse tree, not the AST.  It ignores all rewrites.  This led to my second question which was, how do I visualize the AST if ANTLRWorks doesn't do it for me?  The answer for that is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856612/visualizing-an-ast-created-with-antlr-in-a-net-environment).

Comment: Only the interpreter shows the parse tree, the debugger can visualize the AST. See my answer for details.