# Java Tree parser output for ANTLR

Tags: java, tree, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I've found a sample template in the ANTLR website, its the Javatreeparser.g, which the site says could produce the AST that I need, but since I'm new to ANTLR, how do I make it show? What I've done so far is placing the grammar file together with my existing java grammar. But I have no idea on how to use and output the AST that I need from the file. How do I do it?

Comment: Michael, also see my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I've found a sample template in the ANTLR website, its the Javatreeparser.g, which the site says could produce the AST that I need,

No, the combined grammar `Java.g` [from the ANTLR wiki](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars) produces a lexer and parser for Java source files. The parser then constructs an AST of this source and this AST can then be used by `JavaTreeParser.g` to traverse it. The tree grammar `JavaTreeParser.g` is *not* used to create an AST. This is done by the parser created from `Java.g`.

> What I've done so far is placing the grammar file together with my existing java grammar.

That is incorrect. The tree grammar `JavaTreeParser.g` expects an AST as input that the parser generated from `Java.g` produced. You can't just plug in another parser (or other tree grammar, for that matter).

> But I have no idea on how to use and output the AST that I need from the file. How do I do it?

See this previous Q&A: [Visualizing an AST created with ANTLR (in a .Net environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856612/visualizing-an-ast-created-with-antlr-in-a-net-environment)

### EDIT

I didn't want to post this immediately, because I wanted you to give it a try yourself first (yes, I'm mean!) ;)

Here's a quick demo:

1. copy the `Java.g` in a directory and remove the `@header{...}` and `@lexer:::header{...}` declarations from it;
2. copy `antlr-3.3.jar` into the same directory;
3. create the files `Main.java` and `Test.java` in this directory (see below).

#### Test.java

```
public class Test {

    int i = 1 + 2;
    String s;

    Test(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

#### Main.java

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("Test.java"));
        JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.javaSource().getTree();
        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

Now generate a lexer and parser:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Java.g
```

Then compile all `.java` source files:

```
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
```

And finally run the `Main` class and pipe the output to a file called `ast.dot`.

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main > ast.dot
```

*(on Windows, do: `java -cp .;antlr-3.3.jar Main > ast.dot`)*

If you now open the file `ast.dot`, you see a [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) representation of the AST produced by the parser. You can visualize this AST by copy-pasting the DOT-source in here: http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com resulting in the following image:

[image]

Comment: @michaelsnowden not that I know of. But there are alternatives like http://www.webgraphviz.com/ . Google surely has more.

Answer (score 3):

I really recommend you to use antlr4.

First, set your CLASSPATH (including antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar) and JAVA_HOME.

Second, generate a lexer and parser from the grammar Java.g4:

```
java -cp antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar Java.g4
```

Third, compile all Java*.java genereated:

```
javac -cp antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar Java*.java
```

Finally, run TestRig:

```
java -cp antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar:. org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Java compilationUnit -gui Test.java
```

You will see AST visually as follows:

[image]