# java lexical analyzer (for mining java code which is able to analyze it semantically)

Tags: java, analyzer, lexical

I want a lexical analyzer for java code. Should I write my own or should i use a pre-existing tool?
Is it possible to make my lexical analyzer behave the same as the Java lexical analyzer, without writing my own Regular Expressions?

For example if i have a class like this:

```
 Class Cat
 {
   public void fun(){ 
    int a;
     a=3;

     int b=0;

     if((a/b==3)||(a/b==0))
     {
         System.out.println("Test");
     }
   }
 }
```

I want its output to look like this

```
class keyword
Cat (id/className)
int a(declaration)
a=3 (assignment)
int b=0 (declaration and assignment) 
if (key word)
((a/b==3)||(a/b==0)) (if condition)
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas..

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061548/java-tree-parser-output-for-antlr

Answer (score 0):

http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/

Eclipse includes a tool for extracting the AST out of Java.