# ANTLR v3: Missing method JavaParser.javaSource() and class JavaParser.javaSource_return

Tags: antlr

With executing org.antlr.Tool in antlr-3.5.1-complete.jar with grammar Java.g (e.g. [Java.g](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g)) there are no method JavaParser.javaSource() and class JavaParser.javaSource_return generated, but in [Java Tree parser output for ANTLR - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061548/java-tree-parser-output-for-antlr). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two posts are not using the same **Java.g** file. For the file you referenced, the entry point is the rule `compilationUnit`, which produces `JavaParser.compilationUnit()` and `JavaParser.compilationUnit_return`.

Comment: The grammar Java.g producing JavaParser.javaSource() and JavaParser.javaSource_return is not longer avaiable in http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html (http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars/ gives 404: Page not found), but in https://github.com/grammarware/slps/tree/master/topics/grammars/java-5/habelitz.

Comment: Unfortunately the grammar JavaTreeParser.g in https://github.com/grammarware/slps/tree/master/topics/grammars/java-5/habelitz, ist not capable for code rewriting purposes depicted in http://danielveselka.blogspot.de/2011/01/antlr-java-source-code-rewrite.html, because there ist not generated a method JavaTreeParser.setTemplateLib(StringTemplateGroup). Elsewhere I could'nt find a capable JavaTreeParser.g file.