# Alternatives in ANTLR rewrite rule

Tags: parsing, antlr

I'm writing a grammar that supports arbitrary boolean expressions. The grammar is used to represent a program, which is later passed through the static analysis tool. The static analysis tool has certain limitations so I want to apply the following rewrite rules:

Strict inequalities are approximated with epsilon:

```
expression_a > expression_b -> expression_a >= expression_b + EPSILON
```

Inequality is approximated using "or" statement:

```
expression_a != expression_b -> expression_a > expression_b || expression_a < expression_b
```

Is there any easy way to do it using ANTLR? Currently my grammar looks like so:

```
comparison          : expression ('=='^|'<='^|'>='^|'!='^|'>'^|'<'^) expression;
```

I'm not sure how to apply a different rewrite rule depending on what the operator is. I want to tree stay as it is if the operator is ("==", "<=" or ">=") and to recursively transform it otherwise, according to the rules defined above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] and to recursively transform it otherwise, [...]

You can do it partly.

You can't tell ANTLR to rewrite `a > b` to `^('>=' a ^('+' b epsilon))` and then define `a != b` to become `^('||' ^('>' a b) ^('<' a b))` and then have ANTLR automatically rewrite both `^('>' a b)` and `^('<' a b)` to `^('>=' a ^('+' b epsilon))` and `^('<=' a ^('-' b epsilon))` respectively.

A bit of manual work is needed here. The trick is that you can't just use a token like `>=` if this token isn't actually parsed. A solution to this is to use [imaginary tokens](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction).

A quick demo:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  AND;
  OR;
  GTEQ;
  LTEQ;
  SUB;
  ADD;
  EPSILON;
}

parse
 : expr
 ;

expr
 : logical_expr
 ;

logical_expr
 : comp_expr ((And | Or)^ comp_expr)*
 ;

comp_expr
 : (e1=mult_expr -> $e1) ( Eq   e2=mult_expr -> ^(AND ^(GTEQ $e1 $e2) ^(LTEQ $e1 $e2))
                         | LtEq e2=mult_expr -> ^(LTEQ $e1 $e2)
                         | GtEq e2=mult_expr -> ^(GTEQ $e1 $e2)
                         | NEq  e2=mult_expr -> ^(OR ^(GTEQ $e1 ^(ADD $e2 EPSILON)) ^(LTEQ $e1 ^(SUB $e2 EPSILON)))
                         | Gt   e2=mult_expr -> ^(GTEQ $e1 ^(ADD $e2 EPSILON))
                         | Lt   e2=mult_expr -> ^(LTEQ $e1 ^(SUB $e2 EPSILON))
                         )?
 ;

add_expr
 : mult_expr ((Add | Sub)^ mult_expr)*
 ;

mult_expr
 : atom ((Mult | Div)^ atom)*
 ;

atom
 : Num
 | Id
 | '(' expr ')'
 ;

Eq    : '==';
LtEq  : '<=';
GtEq  : '>=';
NEq   : '!=';
Gt    : '>';
Lt    : '<';
Or    : '||';
And   : '&&';
Mult  : '*';
Div   : '/';
Add   : '+';
Sub   : '-';
Num   : '0'..'9'+ ('.' '0'..'9'+)?;
Id    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space : ' ' {skip();};
```

The parser generated from the grammar above will produce the following:

---

`a == b`

[image]

---

`a != b`

[image]

---

`a > b`

[image]

---

`a < b`

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know that you could use multiple rewrite rules inside one statement. (BTW, how do you generate these diagrams? ANTLRWorks?)

Comment: @cheshire, you're welcome. And yes, the AST-images are from ANTLRWorks' debugger (not the interpreter!). You can also generate them through code, see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856612/visualizing-an-ast-created-with-antlr-in-a-net-environment